# How to manipulate wordpress template tags' output

Tags: theme-development, filters

take `the_category()` as an example:

Here is the output of the_category function in the wordpress loop:

```
    <ul class="post-categories">
        <li>
          <a href="http://example.com/category/another-category/" rel="category tag">
            Another Category
          </a>
       </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://example.com/category/uncategorized/" rel="category tag">
             Uncategorized
          </a>
        </li>
   </ul>
```

so we need a way to add attributes like some other classes, data attributes and ... to the list so it outputs something like this:

```
<ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
            <li>
          <a href="http://example.com/category/another-category/" rel="category tag">
            Another Category
          </a>
       </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://example.com/category/uncategorized/" rel="category tag">
             Uncategorized
          </a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would bet one of these would be an appropriate place to modify that output:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Category_and_Term_Filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I managed to manipulate the output of the_category() template tag.

functions.php:

```
function add_post_category_list_attrs($the_list) {
$list_id = "post-categories-id";
$category_title = __("Categories");

$list_trigger = sprintf('<a href="#" data-dropdown="%s" aria-controls="%s" aria-expanded="false" class="cat-list-trigger">%s</a>',
                        $list_id, $list_id, $category_title);

$the_list = substr_replace($the_list, $list_trigger, 0 ,0);

$the_list = str_replace('<ul class="post-categories">',
                        sprintf('<ul class="f-dropdown" id="%s" data-dropdown-content aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">',
                                $list_id),
                        $the_list);

return $the_list;
}

if( ! is_admin() ){
    add_filter('the_category', 'add_post_category_list_attrs');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For lots of WordPress template tags, including `the_categories()` you can't change the HTML output. Instead, you can use something like `get_the_categories()` and loop through the results to create your own HTML.

```
<ul id="whatever" data-attribute="you" class="want">
<?php
    $categories = get_the_category();
    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) :
        foreach( $categories as $category ) :
?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->name ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $category->name ); ?></a></li>
<?php
        endforeach;
    endif;
?>
</ul>
```

The above version uses some standard WP methods to clean up the output of each bit being printed (esc_url, esc_html...). A more straightforward, if potentially risky, method could look something like this within the `foreach` (depending on your permalink structure):

```
echo '<li><a href="/' . $category->taxonomy . '/' . $category->category_nicename. '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a></li>';
```

Comment: Don't do `get_category_link( $category->term_id )`, it is expensive as it makes an unnecessary db call. Rather do `get_category_link( $category )`,  because if you pass the whole object, `get_category_link` do not need to make a call to db to get the category object ;-)